# ERROR at line 1: ORA-00911: invalid character ORA-06512: at line 17

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am not a frequent user of database & once in a while i need to create/run/execute a few PL/SQL blocks. I have a similar situation right now, where I have the below block which while executing as SYS as SYSDBA in oracle database user throws the error :-

```html
DECLARE 
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at line 17
```

The PL/SQL Block is as below :-

```html
DECLARE
TYPE RefCurTyp IS REF CURSOR;
alter_tbl VARCHAR2(200);
a_null  CHAR(1);
tbl VARCHAR2(200);
clmn VARCHAR2(200);
dtyp VARCHAR2(200) ;
dlth VARCHAR2(200);
c RefCurTyp;
BEGIN
open c for 'select utc.table_name, utc.column_name, utc.data_type, utc.data_length FROM user_tab_columns utc,  user_tables ut
WHERE utc.data_type = ''VARCHAR2'' AND utc.char_used =''B''  AND ut.table_name = utc.table_name';
LOOP
dbms_output.put_line(clmn);
FETCH c INTO tbl, clmn, dtyp, dlth;
EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'alter table '||tbl||' modify ('||clmn||' '||dtyp||'('||dlth||' CHAR))';
END LOOP;
CLOSE c;
END;
```

Even after pounding my head on it for 3 days i am unable to figure out the issue with this. Any input is appreciated.

While executing the same code via TOAD i get :-
[image]

Comment: Generally when getting errors with dynamic SQL it's useful to add a `dbms_output()` call to display exactly what is about to be executed. You are presumably at least getting a number of table names in your output now (if you've set serveroutput on, of course), so you should be abel to see which table it's failing on already. What is different about that one? I'd guess it has a column with a quoted identifier that includes something odd, but can only speculate. Displaying the actual generated alter command should make it obvious.

Comment: Also - why are you altering tables owned by SYS? That doesn't sound like a good idea at all.

Comment: dlth is length... you try to change type to `modify A varchar2(10 CHAR)`... to me it looks as incorrect syntax, your dynamic sql should be smth like `modify A varchar2(10)`

Comment: Do you have a set of sample data you can share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dbms_output` to display the dynamic statement you are executing. To make sure you see and execute the same thing it's simpler to put the statement into a variable (you have one you aren't using). If you change the cursor type you don't need the local variables though, you can construct the statement as part of the cursor query, and then refer to it multiple times; you also won't have to escape your single quotes:

```
set serveroutput on

BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT 'alter table ' || utc.table_name || ' modify (' || utc.column_name || ' '
      || utc.data_type || '(' || utc.data_length || ' CHAR))' as alter_stmt
    FROM user_tab_columns utc
    JOIN user_tables ut ON ut.table_name = utc.table_name
    WHERE utc.data_type = 'VARCHAR2' AND utc.char_used ='B'
  )
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(r.alter_stmt);
    execute immediate r.alter_stmt;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I suspect you have a table or column name that contains an invalid character and was created with a quoted identifier. That will probably be obvious from the output you see immediately before it fails. You can easily add double quotes to all of the identifiers by concatenating them as part of the statement generation:

```
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT 'alter table "' || utc.table_name || '" modify ("' || utc.column_name || '" '
      || utc.data_type || '(' || utc.data_length || ' CHAR))' as alter_stmt
    FROM user_tab_columns utc
    JOIN user_tables ut ON ut.table_name = utc.table_name
    WHERE utc.data_type = 'VARCHAR2' AND utc.char_used ='B'
  )
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(r.alter_stmt);
    execute immediate r.alter_stmt;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

---

You said you're running this while connected as SYS, and you're looking at `user_tables`, so you are altering tables owned by SYS - which seems like a very bad idea. Even if you don't intend to modify built-in data dictionary tables, this will do so, and that would imply you've been creating your own objects in the SYS schema - which is generally considered a very bad idea. You should create a separate user account and only create and modify objects in that schema.

In my 11g instance SYS has a table that generates output from my first query as:

```
alter table _default_auditing_options_ modify (A VARCHAR2(1 CHAR));
```

... which would get ORA-00911 because of the underscores. If the identifiers are quoted then it would work:

```
alter table "_default_auditing_options_" modify ("A" VARCHAR2(1 CHAR));
```

... but, once again, you should *not* be altering built-in tables.

Comment: Big +1 for 'dont ever do this im SYS schema'. I see a dead database on the horizon.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that was very helpful.. I will avoid SYS as try it as a different user.